# Копирование данных из поля <input> в значение ключа JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, form

Здравствуйте. Как сделать так, чтобы в customerContact копировалось значение из поля E-mail?

```
<form class="form1" action="
https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml
" method="post"> 
<input required name="shopId" value="00000" type="hidden"/> 
<input required name="scid" value="00000" type="hidden"/> 
<input type='hidden' required name="sum" value="1799" > 
<input class="name" type='text' name="customerNumber" placeholder="Ф.И.О" size="64"/> 
<input class="emeil" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="custEmail" size="64"/> 
<input name="ym_merchant_receipt" value='{"customerContact": "+79250000000","taxSystem": 2,"items": [{"quantity": 1,"price": {"amount": 1799.00},"tax": 1,"text": "Яблоки"}]}' type="hidden"/>
</form>
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

если добавить `id="xxx"` (иначе обращаться как `$("input[name=....])`) к искомому полю, то как то так?
*зы: в `class="emeil"` тоже опечатка была*

```js
$(".email").keyup(function(){
   var data = JSON.parse($("#xxx").val());   
   data.customerContact = $(this).val();
   $("#xxx").val(JSON.stringify(data));
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form1" action="
https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml
" method="post"> 
<input required name="shopId" value="00000" type="hidden"/> 
<input required name="scid" value="00000" type="hidden"/> 
<input type='hidden' required name="sum" value="1799" > 
<input class="name" type='text' name="customerNumber" placeholder="Ф.И.О" size="64"/> 
<input class="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="custEmail" size="64"/> 
<input id="xxx" name="ym_merchant_receipt" value='{"customerContact": "+79250000000","taxSystem": 2,"items": [{"quantity": 1,"price": {"amount": 1799.00},"tax": 1,"text": "Яблоки"}]}' type="hidden"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Не работает, к сожалению, по-прежнему выдает номер телефона +79250000000 вместо введенного e-mail

Comment: @IgorSchekotihin давайте вы выполните код, откроете инструменты бразуера, ткнете в инспекторе в скрытое поле, и начнете изменять `email`.

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем обработчик события `change` на поле `email`, И там при каждом изменении значения поля взял значение скрытого поля, преобразовал в `object`, Изменил значения свойства `customerContact` в объекте, и в конце с ново преобразовал объект в строку и поменял значение скрытого поля.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.custEmail').on('change',function(){
 var obj = JSON.parse($('.ym_merchant_receipt').val());
 obj.customerContact = $(this).val();
 $('.ym_merchant_receipt').val(JSON.stringify(obj));
        console.log($('.ym_merchant_receipt').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form1" action="
https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml
" method="post"> 
<input required name="shopId" value="00000" type="hidden"/> 
<input required name="scid" value="00000" type="hidden"/> 
<input type='hidden' required name="sum" value="1799" > 
<input class="name" type='text' name="customerNumber" placeholder="Ф.И.О" size="64"/> 
<input class="emeil" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" name="custEmail" size="64"/> 
<input name="ym_merchant_receipt" value='{"customerContact": "+79250000000","taxSystem": 2,"items": [{"quantity": 1,"price": {"amount": 1799.00},"tax": 1,"text": "Яблоки"}]}' type="hidden"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Не работает, к сожалению, по-прежнему выдает номер телефона +79250000000 вместо введенного e-mail

Comment: @IgorSchekotihin фокус должен пропадать от `input`, а если при каждом клике то надо перехватить событие `keyup` например, вместо `change`.и еще одно посмотрите какие ошибки у вас там в кансоле. может до этого какая то ошибка `js` есть у вас в коде, и после этого не какие скрипты работать не будут.