# Как в форме оплаты Yandex Money сделать так, чтобы отправлялись письма с чеком покупателям, а не мне!

Tags: javascript, html, json, form, yandex-money

Ставлю скрипт отсюда - [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685007/Копирование-данных-из-поля-input-в-значение-ключа-json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685007/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-input-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0-json), всё равно письма приходят на почту указанную в customerContact по умолчанию. Т.е. смысл этого кода? Если я правильно понял, должен быть такой, что значение customerContact меняется автоматом при отправке платежа на то что указано в **input class="email"** . Но, увы на тот имейл, который вводят, значение не меняется, в итоге все письма приходят на установленную мною почту (мою). Я не специалист и не разбираюсь в скриптах, может что не так делаю )) Или, если есть возможность подскажите как сделать чтобы работало, я отблагодарю! Вот сама форма - http://anastasiyaagranovich.ru/oplata

В head добавил это:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/templates/shaper_doctor/js/customer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Вот это в customer.js:

```
$(".email").keyup(function(){
   var data = JSON.parse($("#xxx").val());   
   data.customerContact = $(this).val();
   $("#xxx").val(JSON.stringify(data));
   
});
```

Вот это в саму форму на сайте

```
    <form action="https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml" method="post">
    <input required name="shopId" value="531700" type="hidden"/>
    <input required name="scid" value="793680" type="hidden"/>
Сумма к оплате:<br> 
    <input required name="sum" value="2100" type="number" min="1" max="2100"><br>
    Номер телефона (<font color="red">*</font>):<br>
    <input class="phone" required name="customerNumber" value="" size="64"/><br>
    Ваше имя:<br>   
    <input name="custName" value="" size="64"/><br>
    Ваш E-mail:<br> 
    <input class="email" name="custEmail" value="" size="64" /><br>
    Ваш ник в Instagram:<br>    
    <input name="orderDetails" value="" size="64"/><br>
    
    <input id="xxx" name="ym_merchant_receipt" value='{"customerContact": "simple@yandex.ru","taxSystem": 2, "items":[{"quantity": 1, "price": {"amount": 1},  "tax": 1,"text": "Вебинар по подготовке к грудному вскармливанию"}]}' type="hidden"/></br>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Оплатить">  
    </form>
```

В итоге все письма приходят на мой адрес **simple@yandex.ru**, который указан в форме. А должны отправляться на те адреса, которые люди будут указывать в поле **input class="email"**. Что со скриптом, что без.

**УВЕРЕН, не только у меня такой вопрос возникает.** Форма собирает имейлы и телефоны, но сделана так что отправляет чеки только на тот телефон или имейл, который указан владельцем формы (на какой то один имейл или телефон). Хотя по закону чеки должны отправляться покупателям, а не предпринимателю! Почему нельзя было сделать сразу в yandex? Ответ - хотят дополнительно заработать! Уже давно выложили бы решение, или заменили свою форму на нормальную! Звоню им, задаю те же вопросы и аргументирую их теми же словами что и сейчас пишу, в ответ - обратитесь к нашим специалистам, естественно они работают не бесплатно... Прошу помочь не только мне, таких как я много! Это просто развод на ровном месте ((

Comment: Спешу вас огорочить - мы не Яндекс. Что-то яндекс не правильно сделал - вы уже второй человек, который попадает на **stackoverflow** и думает, что это сайт яндекса. Скажите пожалуйста, как вы сюда перешли?

Comment: Причем тут yandex? Я знаю что этот сервис не  yandex! Что за комментарий! Здесь люди делятся решениями проблем касательно веб-программирования. База решений так сказать. И я здесь задаю вопрос, чтобы люди знающие помогли мне разобраться в проблеме. Решение которое я написал выше, находится здесь на сайте, называется иначе (по непонятному для обычного человека). Я решил перезадать вопрос "по-русски", сказать что решение не работает и жду помощи.

Comment: Перешел из поиска в яндексе. Искал ответ на вопрос который написал выше. Нашел решение здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685007/Копирование-данных-из-поля-input-в-значение-ключа-json Но оно не работает! Там комментировать не могу, т.к. маленький уровень. И написать как автору, тоже не нашел. Вот и решил свою тему создать.

Comment: Ну вы даете! Вам напомнить ваш первоначальный вопрос? Вот как он звучал: **Ставлю ваш скрипт, всё равно письма приходят на почту указанную в customerContact по умолчанию. Т.е. смысл вашго кода, если я правильно понял, должен быть такой, что значение customerContact меняется автоматом при отправке платежа на то что указано в input class="email"**. Чей **ВАШ СКРИПТ**?

Comment: Вопрос переформулировали совсем по другому. Из белого сделали черное. И возмущаетесь моим комментарием)))

Comment: Я сначала думал, что пишу вопрос личным сообщением человеку, который предложил вариант решения проблемы. Оказалось, я создал новый вопрос на всеобщее обозрение и, человек, которому было адресовано послание, естественно его не видит. Это я понял только после вашего комментария )) Думаю, что за комментарий )) Потом дошло, как до жирафа, но дошло )) Поэтому переформулировал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в файле *customer.js* сделайте привязку события на загрузку документа.

Ваш скрипт в *customer.js* выполняется до того, как документ полностью загружен. Соответственно `.email` не находит, на событие не подписывается.

Вот так будет лучше:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".email").on('input', function() {
    var data = JSON.parse($("#xxx").val());
    data.customerContact = $(this).val();
    $("#xxx").val(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml" method="post">
  <input required name="shopId" value="531700" type="hidden" />
  <input required name="scid" value="793680" type="hidden" /> Сумма к оплате:<br>
  <input required name="sum" value="2100" type="number" min="1" max="2100"><br> Номер телефона (
  <font color="red">*</font>):<br>
  <input class="phone" required name="customerNumber" value="" size="64" /><br> Ваше имя:<br>
  <input name="custName" value="" size="64" /><br> Ваш E-mail:<br>
  <input class="email" name="custEmail" value="" size="64" /><br> Ваш ник в Instagram:<br>
  <input name="orderDetails" value="" size="64" /><br>

  <input id="xxx" name="ym_merchant_receipt" value='{"customerContact": "aleksandr.brilliant@yandex.ru","taxSystem": 2, "items":[{"quantity": 1, "price": {"amount": 1},  "tax": 1,"text": "Вебинар по подготовке к грудному вскармливанию"}]}' type="hidden"
  />

  <input type="submit" value="Оплатить">
</form>
```

Comment: РАБОТАЕТ! Подтверждаю, проверил, всё прекрасно работает. Искренняя благодарность за то, что вошли в ситуацию, отнеслись с пониманием и помогли решить вопрос. Хотелось бы вас отблагодарить, как я могу это сделать?

Comment: @АлександрБриллиант отметьте ответ как правильный, и отметьте полезность

Comment: @АлександрБриллиант если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как правильный - галочка напротив ответа.